# How to parse Binary XML post request in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a pdf from a post request I'm making to a SOAP server. I'm sending an xml to this server and it returns me back an xml response. The problem is that I'm not able to parse this response. It seems to be returning back a binary (pdf) but also returns back xml content.
I google around and spent already 6 hours trying to sort it out, but not able to. Sorry if this is trivial, but could anyone give me a direction on this?

Here's my code:

```
import requests


url = "https://myendpoint"

payload = "mySoapXMlPayload"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/xml",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.15.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "ca4ab667-9282-43f5-a382-0501f3829696,9a5bf8c0-891b-4ecc-9ecc-edb687f81c17",
    'Host': "connect-dev.bla.bla.blah",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'content-length': "1783",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
content =response.text
```

Much appreciated!

this is return I've got but can't parse as there's a mix of binary with XML:

```
--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146208@ibm.com>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><NS1:Header><NS2:msgContext xmlns:NS2="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:svc:task:registration:check:v1"><msgSolution>SNSWServices</msgSolution><msgCorrelationID>b8c86df5-f998-4dd6-bd3f-af9a92554cae</msgCorrelationID><msgTimestamp>2019-06-14T02:56:07.452Z</msgTimestamp></NS2:msgContext></NS1:Header><NS1:Body><NS3:getFreeRegoCheckByPlateNumberResponse xmlns:NS3="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:svc:task:registration:check:v1" xmlns:veh="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:vehicle:v2" xmlns:bas="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:common:basictype:v2" xmlns:reg="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:registration:v2" xmlns:sys="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:system:v2" xmlns:cust="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:party:v2"><ResponseDetails><reg:IDType>RoadsRegistrationAndLicencing</reg:IDType><reg:FRCPDF><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:1.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146209@ibm.com"></xop:Include></reg:FRCPDF><reg:VehicleDetails><veh:Plate><bas:PlateNumber>XJ78LK</bas:PlateNumber><bas:PlateType>O</bas:PlateType></veh:Plate><veh:VehicleID>66038029</veh:VehicleID><veh:VehicleModel><veh:Manufacturer><sys:Code>FORD</sys:Code><sys:Description>FORD</sys:Description></veh:Manufacturer><veh:ManufactureYear>2011</veh:ManufactureYear><veh:ManufactureMonth>11</veh:ManufactureMonth><veh:Model><sys:Code>00RIGID</sys:Code><sys:Description>00RIGID</sys:Description></veh:Model><veh:BodyShape><sys:Code>TTF</sys:Code><sys:Description>TABLE TOP WITH FITTINGS</sys:Description></veh:BodyShape></veh:VehicleModel><veh:VehicleColour><sys:Code>40</sys:Code><sys:Description>BLUE</sys:Description></veh:VehicleColour><veh:VehicleType><sys:Code>RT</sys:Code><sys:Description>GOODS VEHICLE - RIGID TRUCK</sys:Description></veh:VehicleType><veh:Last4DigitalOfVINChassisNumber>R009</veh:Last4DigitalOfVINChassisNumber><veh:TareWeight>5840</veh:TareWeight><veh:GrossVehicleMass>12001</veh:GrossVehicleMass></reg:VehicleDetails><reg:RegistrationEndDate>2019-04-01</reg:RegistrationEndDate><reg:RegistrationStatus>Active</reg:RegistrationStatus><reg:TransactionID><sys:ID>A-4000243140</sys:ID><sys:SourceSystem>DRIVES</sys:SourceSystem></reg:TransactionID><reg:PolicyDetails><reg:InsurerCode>34</reg:InsurerCode><reg:InsurerName>NRMA</reg:InsurerName><reg:EndDate>2019-04-01</reg:EndDate></reg:PolicyDetails><reg:ConcessionOnRego>N</reg:ConcessionOnRego><reg:Conditions><reg:RegistrationCondition><reg:CodeCategory>V</reg:CodeCategory><reg:Code>HE</reg:Code><reg:Description>HVIS EXEMPT - HVAIS INSP REQUIRED</reg:Description></reg:RegistrationCondition></reg:Conditions><reg:ConfigurationDetails><reg:Code>RT0</reg:Code><reg:Description>RIGID TRUCK (NO TRAILERS)</reg:Description></reg:ConfigurationDetails></ResponseDetails><SystemMessages><sys:Message><sys:Identifier>SUCCESS</sys:Identifier><sys:Classification>BUSINESS</sys:Classification><sys:Severity>SUCCESS</sys:Severity><sys:Message>Success</sys:Message></sys:Message></SystemMessages></NS3:getFreeRegoCheckByPlateNumberResponse></NS1:Body></NS1:Envelope>
--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146209@ibm.com>

%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 200/Length 21777/Height 55/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream
����ExifMM* ����(1 �2ԇi� 
��'
��'Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)2016:02:25 15:27:15�0221����Ƞ7nv(~�HH����Adobe_CM��Adobed����       



��,�"��
��?    
  
3!1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE£t6�U�e���u��F'���������������Vfv��������7GWgw��������5!1AQaq"2����B#�R��3$b�r��CScs4�%���&5��D�T�dEU6te����u��F���������������Vfv��������'7GWgw�������?����͇~H��� �v���.#�wT��3���=Sʭ~׀�A�F=����m����穪ݟhV��=�}p���0��v�q%�5؟g� ��Wk�I�X����S�\U-u](̵�ج{uk�eY���smP�f�mó��x�8�N��    �>�%�Q�7���fU[i�ܖ�1�0n���@fVV��,��/�ߤ�髸�Yz����u֜�ܛ��U�M�mf�d=�^5N��db���{?��.|ߋ~9����S�TEWe�z��B�ëw�m����w.�?��ث>�,�������^�K��1�7��?I����qնyLS��c��&�)J'�'����>��3]���3^_�Mv���9�s[?�P���a����9��鍷�S��{9��sѰ�m�ɇ��PWGO��]���׶�(������e�����z�z~���U��h��*����{��b<DX�N7�8�Q���>A/�-���,��xY�� �`ö͞��}$��Ճl�*�{*m����6��5�{-���c�O}lZk�����?��ricn���V��}�������[o�4��F�V�{D��u��u�u\�Y�����ls{�ns��}��7Uen�c�2ΟV=w�������V�O�7���{:�_lv��Z�ͫ~%�Y����9��wz��zv{�w�*���Iy��}3�up����U��s�4�ַ{�߁���ו���]����Kh���u�C>���ԟ�  ���|.�vVʝ�A��c�;gۙ�6���vS�׫�e�㷂���\F��l������^2�L9d�ynF��z��m���;zw�7���[3����0N��fU�Ӳ_CwT��[(��k�6[��
�ٺ�_mU���=�fU��YG����[�C�_�   �Eu2�i��eu�R=?s�ٹr��Wq>����cS��c�}J��o����,f�7���g��V��]��I&�I$�J������>�n���e���弲�Ǽ��P�۳���zJ���ٌ�6f�P��Ye��T��.��32�N�S�Y����^ϴbߑ�͘��9_��G�睏��2�j���m�Zm����m������_G����V��M���=:y���!UU��w�dYQnUl�v[�W��半�-����~�
#!�?���6}_�N�Uc8��2�hk�Z�ux̢����S=��7�хF>.=eaZ1-9���}�d�m4P��n�<��m���z�S�V�ӫU��־�~]_X02M��gG}l�����Zܛ�]_C����\�������>�ӚY���Ns1�2-���N�=,}�6�M������ݍ�:������!R��S��[�FM����>�s:�vuM��}���w�k��z���v�U.�����?Ѯ��#}"�\��۹�\c3K�~��+_���;�8��Y�_"�����N�W�9����nc�c?1u�Z?�ʿ�����'������y̼�dTG� P�N��i���/��̳2�B�qZ׼�k��6�Kv�����~�t�e��ǻ���X�\�6���[�V��S����Ԯ����U��`��etF�:�}<��rq��:�z���ik]���m�����]fmy�dul���o��5���2�o���j�ƺ��O���/�]_��oU5�ѹW�Z:�-Ĺ�4�u����g������~����pݟNM
��ǳ҆��sO��۷�/?����?�u>��l��Y�cd`݉Y}��:���=��u�T�f=wU�oS���GE̩ٖ��eft�s�3]��+���{��}]?��}��z6��Tّ�?�U]��"�U�=�z�A�̾����&�|�s���!��U��;�[[��Q��Э�+�\j���{s^�6]CMU3ףG�����&����U�\{�~F1����`�����Fʙc�����̟�W}����f�~���&�Ӱ�����>�[in8{w�2m�;���ȧ}�g�ޗ�?��F��bz)��~�t��6�v��ͦ����_���l�cX��m�}?��zW~��=4k:�F����V^�NM���HcE0
�6��O���M�?G���?��G��T��[�3?�Yml���X3Amn�F�Yk�Ί�?N�Y��!�Ս��c��_��Z��e��U}��5�)̧&����z���61��
T.�J�:,���w�u�����-�u�V��MO���{�G}?B�k6}�OS��}t�M��굖5�{��ok���o�j���@������~e5��:��nH�����9?g��Y�E�����������g/*�qge?���.��,�f,�]Y�?g�W�����ڱ�}7��V�xbF���?Z�vu�0�7[�N.[m���r�W��̧��e�?E�Z�F+��^��m����j�&ڜ܏Y�����[�[�����>�վ��_S�w3��#�ӓ�.��Z��1�[�V
&g�Qe,���H�+7���t��rz�E��>��j�m����2�=ގE_����1���e�u���c����fc�1\-a��c��w~����h����.�����Z_V3��k�7K뤟Q��?�W�~�b_�����q��_�N�SS��ߡ�Ǫ�>�����hC��T���S�^Q~vp����î����{z��SgMO�}������?����c޼�g����>�_�?����Iꭥ���ik�6�6���]�;�U�����7���=�9���ll��f]�o��k�Ŧ�5�ȩ���z�c?��k�OV:�~����O�vo�w����}/��?�~��w�m��A��i�j~����O���Չ�?���o�����7���7�잏�^��h��]ѭ�~����f55}W��uvZ�����mt���SAۿ�}�_�_���Y�����X�K�*�qr�-h`�p����{��:�~��:�����߳z�i�}=�&g����~��/G���������[����W�.��;v�LNݲ}��������^����J�C��:u������\������fg�����g�[�^^��췷�U[���
�6�j�~�ɕ�����\�����k�[�w��M�O��z`���}_־��o�/�E�}e��6��m��13��]�K�I��8߂Fť�ϩ�>����K��mŹ�J�~��z��X�M���c}'��=����X_[F7K�۝_�\��mf�mx�ͪ��w�M�m��o��?����+�[��a������{��~��cٿ���I��^���~�/�������ߴ����Uޯھ��
��~����_ٿ�}/��S����8h_��W�w����R�z~M��v�b�*��+��(}��Q�#��c-�Y��o�+�}o��*mv-��[�J�
C�^D��}�og�V;_��7�
���l���n~���T�~��o��ً�������Og����uz�������/D��g�������}��'���Q#­S�߮�����Σ�˯-�ю�Mwى�dZ�K����Ʈ�����7��1�g��r-fM��nuU?>��z
��[�����-�c��_�}_�.C����I����o}�+�>�߳���y���=Og�~����������Y��Uޟ��h���j����Fڿ�ϵ~��ϳ?�y���ڝ�z-Z��/��gu�:f#�q���sm:����>���Z͹�n�_�Ϩ�湻��L�������f�7�Ge�g������[�OS��7��)4�D�$�H)I$�JRI$������Photoshop 3.08BIM>Z%GZ%G"Transport--OL_crop8BIM%\ X~�dg���(�Q�H8BIM:printOutputPstSboolInteenumInteClrmprintSixteenBitboolprinterNameTEXTBrother MFC-9450CDNprintProofSetupObjcProof Setup
proofSetupBltnenumbuiltinProof    proofCMYK8BIM;-printOutputOptionsCptnboolClbrboolRgsMboolCrnCboolCntCboolLblsboolNgtvboolEmlDboolIntrboolBckgObjcRGBCRd  doub@o�Grn doub@o�Bl  doub@o�BrdTUntF#RltBld UntF#RltRsltUntF#Pxl@R
vectorDataboolPgPsenumPgPsPgPCLeftUntF#RltTop UntF#RltScl UntF#Prc@YcropWhenPrintingboolcropRectBottomlongcropRectLeftlong
cropRectRightlongcropRectToplong8BIM�HH8BIM&?�8BIM
8BIM8BIM�    8BIM'
8BIM�H/fflff/ff���2Z5-8BIM�p��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������8BIM@@8BIM8BIM]7�RMSGov_logo_2col_RGB�7nullboundsObjcRct1Top longLeftlongBtomlong7Rghtlong�slicesVlLsObjcslicesliceIDlonggroupIDlongoriginenumESliceOrigin
autoGeneratedTypeenum
ESliceTypeImg boundsObjcRct1Top longLeftlongBtomlong7Rghtlong�urlTEXTnullTEXTMsgeTEXTaltTagTEXTcellTextIsHTMLboolcellTextTEXT  horzAlignenumESliceHorzAligndefault   vertAlignenumESliceVertAligndefaultbgColorTypeenumESliceBGColorTypeNone topOutsetlong
leftOutsetlongbottomOutsetlongrightOutsetlong8BIM(?�8BIM8BIM8BIM��,�R������Adobe_CM��Adobed����          







��7���� !01"4@2$"!2B#1RbA3C$�v 0r�SQq�a���DU�
!"21ABRr �aq�b��#0@Q�����CSc��3s�����HgX{�}���x����>y�s&���[x�0��y~�4��~δ�z]o��w��w��8���O"���D,c/���A��3p���z�Q뾾9�6���߂Y��6Τ(��)
���C�Cyk�lʀ������I�Q��.շ�������j��f�i2MixV)ם��k-b��躒�T�Np�=/��з�놔��Oy���(�d��A����f��YTk���&S��sp��5�"y���y�Nw|--��?��G��M�:m�ܫ��H9Bp�c_�e�Y��l��Q�r�O�<��$����ͥv����.a�G�i����8�/(R]RR���
�)h�Iad-�'�ǭ׊I��h+܀�)���S�   ����*K�/�kđ@%a�����R��]�ȥ�˂G�����ͯ��{��:
!`�R('��+H/��ZT}Ki*�7�,�Jc��RO��۪���[4�
�Tǿ_w�HM��-�u2
Ų�C���h�]��
��a�)���m�N:;x�0<�T��\�B�IRT�$��
���嵤8�SV�  Z^<�ӯ&�q!%i
�#n��+�{gҺKEJ�$4�Ag�<4��4���b-�K�)#�@��0�>��"���
�վl}�m|wI��yc�
�/7�E@���~����|�q��v�vsu����ݹe�J���)*�6��\�U��7]n͛a������QN}�O*5ؚ䂒M'�]�)<��<z�Q���4�Sx��-��[u8T��B��:�P���E<��i<�J��Jx    U�V����K�0-$e,�t*�Ar�IErJ��/��S���d����+����(���AA`�qKZ���Oj�ب��R=�^>HI�    <���i@���X����DBOO<�J�qPW    @��On��"�{qE`PX5ڻ��(��J��UD��U\��E(��Ҁ���q@Wڇ����o(�2����5A����m�Šq\�R�G$c4�Ghk�m�~_��osorǫm�  �.W��;��Ou/f<��c2�ۜ�]��/�b����?��  ٖn^ԲE���_Y����;y   |zQ��y�L�ՙ����o�L�2�bʱ�[�����N��d?��d�w�m��z�l��'�wl^㥰Y���9�rg?���>��Ʀ�l�]���#W�)���k'
�l;L`�76��xԷ1���ߏ� X    Lz��*�P�C���%�[N�dn�t
ne���r��v�M��m��VSm�vTSt����7w9��QܖvU�6p��o��+(��
Q�&��F�ȣ��}_;��z��t���6�<��~�xݥw��/�(�n�vQe��wY
�7�Ƿ���V�����^R��%�rb6���{�Sg���Hn"��?�q�m�����s���(|��)��m8�����a'1����y�����{7����_Ns���Q�i3K�<�-�,�ӌ��$�|x��3y��[I�+g��y��N{^\���D_IX�o��r
����&�Ⱥ�?����<������c�u���3n�f9Kݕ���n�޵��f7����d��
�!Ai�<�ѷ���r��n'0�e7'����nAcy��P��k��7{�e��*��K�'?a{�M�35o���Գ���.��<o?����M����?D��G����u�� +G�r/�@�߳���G��i��F���ޕ�w�(��
2���`&QYU��C�  �)�a7kU    KmP�6i�٣��P'���6��-�)��*(�T&�ݔl�
D{`�#y[�n�.�YQ
��*#9��q�c��lwwʉ�ҚH�tP�J���9�wYC@:T
6HG}@�V��H�@e�>�H�Yօ>ʌDvu���+��:b�͔�f�,�*��2$&�����̌M���%�2u��
�m��Q�W���r�A�Q�u�eVI~�����Q@�ҝ�Aof���   ��8��t�A�/SkK*�ZYr7w���.e[   �J�e��B'�+s�V������ҁk�7>�@�K'��)��Φ&��* 3�įKs��=��?M��0=�H1��G�8̷0��1��/��ySs����7�<��'�����l��
��kv���S&2r�Y�9�����wgUDj�-��Lad�ٵN�1���N��u�^m�v�j��T���cs�io��h��S���I��V�R�£��Y)|(�2<�:PY�CJ�gC�5G��7KE���W�߷��M��e9w_=/�
��hvd�x�o�owY+z��O�g�M�˽浪W�S�PMU�8���c0>Ti�
�7\�>H�2��ʭPP�����o16��A���on�7b���E�ӫL�1Q�M��{ۃ����;�s.5��5n�Y7���Ž[�U���*w�����mRo�7j��G���fH�����D �8�rE�� ��!̴��B��
��'�!�PV��ѐ�Bs��P�Ҭ�_��?�#�r��`�.�{fzN���z��������p�;M���[��
hT��bO���"��,��)�l�q�
�,D�ƫۦـ�L���������h��R��Hr�E#�W\�I.lhPO}-�ZC�K�vmJ�A�IL���(������y���"�t̔�ږ�������?��ѿ��V�S�XSOL���=�^�N ��VF,mLΉ>�=��{��� ��!��mYA�D��(�����J�b����^
"d{[B�Bq�Oon����h�.�qN1(��>c������\!�Wk�^iL�m������~�-g��i  ~�_S��  #4Eb���LbQn͑�M���V��Z�(.��V��A���j�fI�۰.
E?n����z�<gV��f.�@����H@t0#��
>�*l�����#�������QY��E���������q�;(\��^e��W,
�X���!ҁi-H�l`�B���w<*�
��6�W7L���X� ρ0�����A��H2Y��E��MsUD�"���D�0�[���������E[3V�(���U�@�$�^'>��i1�0O¤�娌�ifk�٠]^d{�QK���N��9�����W.Nqx*��ޫ���a���(��BJ�2Ӹn��8�UZ�1nF�*��:I]�uJ��{�u}���?KXKIk�c,9�j��I���֪�h �bN��S�Z�5���S�~Y�e��5V�Y5Xj��'J���H�h�k>f��X������TU��2S  ���1~g��������&��Xb��P
��{NV,��=�O�7�p�h�֜��W�<�'M�d5��}�beV���O���ޑi������\��HX�p�q�6Or��0�)�Ŏ�����x�H���e� �6 ����+5�_鎮��92X<caXZ�T'�]Wwhj    �������|�z���I���u�)�/�����QY��S�C��&�;;�2Qڥ�Y!��*�����p�iR�P�1:���%ߴ@�9w������61�����/&/�E�R�r���HH���~��tb�o(�������bU+'E�p00R+ 'G��z�e��
��U��^�I�H�f13�uH���1r[x������A]ױ>��FA��y�cw����u�T�R�O(٣�[�j�o�5W$�#C{n�GI�~��j�W�0�y�i�9PJ�j���S��x�rt�T�n ������m�#SٵG��2މXX{�s�&͔�wq�͵鯊{��R���Ȍ��1��f|E�z&B�+x\z�qvR-fS!�?*C�es������~[rc�֪e/��;�$d�~=]e0��~E��Z>ĵ�;Uݢ&eG�L����Z�hԦ��AUr8���py+̤�~���=)9��L������z�ÛVq��5�^�����J����P�ѫ����9 ]����Ԋ*��j�W^��2�';�p�a�R��3����<mBK�Ȯ���Z�a �"">Ȏ�����ṵ|�U��8������"���'�d'Ā�߽�#|�:�Ɇ$/�F9<d��${���[�gŧIuo�<.n�b���+P��mq�X��8o�D����m�sX+I!�;/@�"ш�У�/->����됯
���4Z�_�*�-yY
��<�m�D�[:��h.��l�� ����fOO�e����eb;�ZZ~�+��Ǳ�&�J�S�zֲ�%�z�F�돭�����n��<�Z�׌�;�%�2E�ϑ���������e��T�a�2>{�SO�����c)w�Ȱ����+�+����P��<{��\_/���_5T�������2G �zH��.���l#���$lA ձX5�V�gZ�}<DOV���w=����89��
���Uq���5��u�sW\��y>?n�J�+��pBrneqi�NH(�j�ez���E����r��,�N)Ԧ�=���Ai�~���p��q����u�2���^���dɕL�Q�����u�\���,�.P��X��=�Ƒa,W��z�^��n1Xp�q��Ʋ�W���o"'D$��Á�"��'���/�����m�-%ج���I��K�B��zO���1�䗸��Ǳ�/d�,6��IkcHg[~`����Hz�Q��1�ɸ��[C]6����Q����FW{[��p<|��U�S����J6���r:��ѽ�5m'��-Q������d���
dZ���^���շ)T�~��Ne�u*%V��&0��FS2RG��e�Eg�j�~`_��խn(�ʡ�/����8�J�+�xi���i!����M����� �W6�ɒ�r@F~���E|��w���y`�|�6��o*�d�hXD�6~е���|o�%�ܚ�dsY?��f�\��1�K�V���+=^9Oʴ���9U�T���h:��a�n}GfH�t�3F�>]`!<K=[���R�C���,�
Oo���1J�&[�׫˦�����F��%$А+*F�
�/W�y| ]���q�:Ш�Yƾ�   �d5�!OL� �l�V�~={��a�2��}
 ���U���y(���ʕ)>K��6���2[d:�&<\��Q�`~&k�t��l��5S   ��0�K�Q��}A�孷W#T�CAoh_��q�����y{I���%�:�9�����վ�j��5�N�}&_�*��!�2��=�оٍ=~W����o��F@j)�W�;Q���;v��ʸ��[�׮6����m�`yi������UM�GE�kJ�ެZ�Ep��Q�I�~�T8O 㜖� �Z٫6*��uH�TĽ�@�u�un}޳�b����r��$��^�h!��c��q�{87$%�+.  ���媮��S�e���ݣR��|�f��Wfx��*&9�N�&��)�F��,��v��G�s�28B+4r�rKDɬ��d� ;h��c;f�oI�0�6;>���B[0��)��i�+�+��[��@�ܤ��v�>�^��|����̿���
[���,&��jHW�j��d���D{u�|_X�s�]~M������Z2Q]b2�
$e>!��^:�g�"J�ٿ�6)�*�4��D}FL����1�K;@���}v�]XY���`����zu����N��a�Ve>/ٮF���*��c�E�q�u��"���*���d�V  z�L��V1v�L�EU��5l�dFT��������t�]�Zci
�%b�KQR:��
H�p'X��OPC�(����?���,�e;�|1�ơhT�
{Akt���׻��ZG��N�$��@R;�0�m>���5��q���� ��6++Z���>?1��'!9�j�WB��2QO� .��k�o{~�z�U|~�]���dUL!*X5K=�/��6_�xO��\_c��V�ȒP��0���魹��WW%6�֪�&Y^���-��^~��e��z��j�Z�#Ќ���DIOn����n�sQ��ّ�B^�M[�����yu��¥��"0�\}��m��d���z�Cu�����s��3��]��o�k9^�,Kj0�qZD(�v
+Կ�㧪��F{�⃒+�X�/�MvF������"U���_��9�8r�����XJ�(1���*���X���lH������/u����z���+��sh�ċY�������B����J�VFg��=�;2_S��R��5y-���"?/�|�����X��t��id��֭�M��~��]��'��|�9ec�
�q��c2:+,k7)D��%G��Z��W�_U��ܕ�����p=�]��s��
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</C[0 0 1]/Border[0 0 0]/BS<</W 0/S/S>>/A<</URI(http://www.ppsr.gov.au)/S/URI>>/Subtype/Link/Rect[327.56 197.59 374.59 208.01]>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 2151/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x��X�r۶}�W�3���0�;���N�6vYI:s�Z�$$���t��gm�D�+Ɍ�-pm,�;�}�z:
X�l:�LGG�G�,a�Q����ב����l>�R� =�%I���ɵ���1D<:X��V�/�gd"�"��o�AED<K鈰�����I�^����4�x�}���:�q��xqM��'���um��C��'Oc�k
��煇zq���T���Z��x���(6���ͺvkm��cO��i��ڬS�x���@|F���C��&/�"<�
Ԯk���"��о��E��ܳ@��i%
�G@!�/��_���R0!��Rp���z�s�^��t��|�\� ��ߎ������6�pϾ���؛�t:�{����+��K�E��~�]\�ʮ��+��� (��`�|�+�(P>c��?�����8�>=e:9�6Kp�����B���V�#��h)a#��� L�?4�l*�P�;9�:vz�'�<!kg0z�k��Zʮo�^��"ӄ�$�����,�y�$�.K#
+�FiH^q{(O�GYA+ăVyT0�J".R��xМf�
�Q�X�(���qA�(��a�0��l�-���V�)C,2Gn�bo-x�vϑ"Ѐ��r\P�����H,�<ˬ~+8�nO�r(+�>G8.b'́F^�a�gXБސo�ҝy¨{"t�Q���7�'l�+���V��y�c!�
i����� �|���㋊�
�7�x�h���Ne���E�Dyw��dV��힡a@�C�!>}��a̅K�8�x��
���3�,�
Z������#!O�F-x�v��0��!eS�;�Bw~�D���61��l�-��Bl��1��ċEJy�4�����̞�a@��Q
8�Q�R'5:"|�ĳ�c��4+���s��4��%    E�j�v{���
��A��J9��eu��·V���aeQV�
=�PO?�c�Y�3�{��
ʮ/�'}1�N�46���*������7|�Qm�B���lh�! ����ː6�d��ؼ�KYwl�Z�C�U+9�+vP[V5}�VsV�xNv��<@z�j��/�Q[�hԇz_��Œ<ط�0
Cn&����:��r��(�
��d����B8�{������a�mt��IF�2A|��.Cx�� �4��T�I��֎��+ٝ����2�T�S]M�l�m[B�^3B�[�������6U+����y�W�~��H��x~Ll��?k�u���Mn/πE@M�<Ss����1"Lu�q��jr��.��cD���Xc2
���ѓOW�������������_�SA��sGe.5�+\�  T����nػ��v�����|�}��8�{�g����Ɠ��<B����a�&��W���K�Z�*���u���0�A�J_)N���k�i�N�+�ض(*��2���&�|���#��Sv�2U�������]-g�&x�0��
�{��@WR��z��D
�нM��t��9g�j`}��%�����l�ޛ����ZCܴrG�Uu]��iU��j������*��k����)kv�*�f�k�l����<�)��۱��R�������pL�zl϶�G*��M�+����R���0�Anp�fӵ|�v�ܞ���0t7^�nV�r]�g�w!q,b�A#[��/w����r���W��9�]oQ��`l �g㞭˃��cE;ƻ6��U(�/�(�}��zE��4@������V��&��!`��jY�4�U�\6ˎ��*�z[��׃�ݾ�V�2$a�A;�����X6��I�И���s�X�Yܘ���yb�n��
]��F��j}s=s�g8��䦚i�U���l�&���oQ>�G诞 ��}����b|�JBlbq�V;���2Gy[�N�#t�������+eS�_�j�\Qͼ���,�U��D��
�'W?C2\M�W��m7ڡ/k5Vڗ��y֕��\U&�_憱�WqC#(�����p��'�]f���r7���T�·
f0��e~YA��~G�x{P1�;�σd����l[�-�����2�i�g���Z���t��^q�u �\�]�-ӹx�&�;$�\j�������'�Zҙ�ÛnZ���������K
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Parent 7 0 R/Contents 6 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</XObject<</img0 4 0 R>>/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R/F2 3 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.42 841.69]/Annots[5 0 R]>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</C[0 0 1]/Border[0 0 0]/BS<</W 0/S/S>>/A<</URI(http://www.service.nsw.gov.au)/S/URI>>/Subtype/Link/Rect[373.65 788.85 450.19 799.27]>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Length 302/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x�}RMk�0��W�A����u��;;��DMܥ�j� ��s�e+c�ѳޓ��Op_�,,ͱ�ࡀ-��3m�a��!����9V���d�!Ir��.8J�ԋ����+�Pv<�-�=
�� �G���&�,X��i��9c#;���Zu���rh��X��!@BGmK�~NvԨ���$?�{��;����0N����3�_�eeC�G(-���>�D,M.��l�Jb���6��k���gq>I+�R���X�B�����5U+4�צ��`�.|7;_v�#Tړ%�
!��3~�-|^�X
endstream
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Parent 7 0 R/Contents 9 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.42 841.69]/Annots[8 0 R]>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica-Bold/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</ITXT(2.1.7)/Type/Pages/Count 2/Kids[1 0 R 10 0 R]>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 7 0 R>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<</Producer(iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT)/ModDate(D:20190722155905+10'00')/CreationDate(D:20190722155905+10'00')>>
endobj
xref
0 13
0000000000 65535 f 
0000024310 00000 n 
0000025218 00000 n 
0000025306 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000021946 00000 n 
0000022091 00000 n 
0000025399 00000 n 
0000024519 00000 n 
0000024671 00000 n 
0000025040 00000 n 
0000025469 00000 n 
0000025515 00000 n 
trailer
<</Root 11 0 R/ID [<f469469c2535de480074a07b05274730><4c9bc260cf57e363a5c75e775071548a>]/Info 12 0 R/Size 13>>
startxref
25638
%%EOF

--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207--
```

Comment: Where to you see XML? That's a binary PDF file.

Comment: that's the bottom of the response 03801174072068118083B18A0DAC827A" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:03801174072068118083B18A0DAC827A"/> <xmpMM:History> <rdf:Seq> <rdf:li stEvt:action="saved" stEvt:instanceID="xmp.iid:0180117407206811822AABABFE165416" stEvt:when="2016-02-25T15:27:15+11:00" stEvt:softwareAgent="Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)" stEvt:changed="/"/> </rdf:Seq> </xmpMM:History> <dc:title> <rdf:Alt> <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Transport-NSWGovt_Gradient-OL_crop</rdf:li> </rdf:Alt> </dc:title> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta>

Comment: @JimGarrison couldn't place the entire response as stackoverflow didn't allowed me to do it. Could you give me a hand then how to parse that? thanks

Comment: If the binary response contains some embedded XML you will have to figure out how to extract the XML string from the PDF.  For that you probably need to find a PDF parser, and that sort of recommendation is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: if you get binary data then better use `response.content` instead of `response.text` because `.text` may convert "new line" chars in all file.

Comment: split it by `--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207` and you get xml and pdf in separated variables but still with headers. Next split by empty line ("\n\n") to get headers and file in different variables. And now you can parse XML and write PDF to file.

Comment: thanks @furas will try that. cheers mate

Comment: all this looks like two files attached in email so maybe some function in module `email` could help.

Comment: it may be mate. It's my first time doing that sort of thing, so thanks for the insights :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have binaries in data so better use `response.content` instead of `response.text` which can convert "new line" in all data.

You can get first line and use it to split data to separated files with headers.

Using empty line `"\n\n"` you can split to headers and file`s content

```
data = b'''--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146208@ibm.com>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><NS1:Header><NS2:msgContext xmlns:NS2="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:svc:task:registration:check:v1"><msgSolution>SNSWServices</msgSolution><msgCorrelationID>b8c86df5-f998-4dd6-bd3f-af9a92554cae</msgCorrelationID><msgTimestamp>2019-06-14T02:56:07.452Z</msgTimestamp></NS2:msgContext></NS1:Header><NS1:Body><NS3:getFreeRegoCheckByPlateNumberResponse xmlns:NS3="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:svc:task:registration:check:v1" xmlns:veh="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:vehicle:v2" xmlns:bas="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:common:basictype:v2" xmlns:reg="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:registration:v2" xmlns:sys="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:system:v2" xmlns:cust="urn:xml-gov-au:nsw:rms:party:v2"><ResponseDetails><reg:IDType>RoadsRegistrationAndLicencing</reg:IDType><reg:FRCPDF><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:1.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146209@ibm.com"></xop:Include></reg:FRCPDF><reg:VehicleDetails><veh:Plate><bas:PlateNumber>XJ78LK</bas:PlateNumber><bas:PlateType>O</bas:PlateType></veh:Plate><veh:VehicleID>66038029</veh:VehicleID><veh:VehicleModel><veh:Manufacturer><sys:Code>FORD</sys:Code><sys:Description>FORD</sys:Description></veh:Manufacturer><veh:ManufactureYear>2011</veh:ManufactureYear><veh:ManufactureMonth>11</veh:ManufactureMonth><veh:Model><sys:Code>00RIGID</sys:Code><sys:Description>00RIGID</sys:Description></veh:Model><veh:BodyShape><sys:Code>TTF</sys:Code><sys:Description>TABLE TOP WITH FITTINGS</sys:Description></veh:BodyShape></veh:VehicleModel><veh:VehicleColour><sys:Code>40</sys:Code><sys:Description>BLUE</sys:Description></veh:VehicleColour><veh:VehicleType><sys:Code>RT</sys:Code><sys:Description>GOODS VEHICLE - RIGID TRUCK</sys:Description></veh:VehicleType><veh:Last4DigitalOfVINChassisNumber>R009</veh:Last4DigitalOfVINChassisNumber><veh:TareWeight>5840</veh:TareWeight><veh:GrossVehicleMass>12001</veh:GrossVehicleMass></reg:VehicleDetails><reg:RegistrationEndDate>2019-04-01</reg:RegistrationEndDate><reg:RegistrationStatus>Active</reg:RegistrationStatus><reg:TransactionID><sys:ID>A-4000243140</sys:ID><sys:SourceSystem>DRIVES</sys:SourceSystem></reg:TransactionID><reg:PolicyDetails><reg:InsurerCode>34</reg:InsurerCode><reg:InsurerName>NRMA</reg:InsurerName><reg:EndDate>2019-04-01</reg:EndDate></reg:PolicyDetails><reg:ConcessionOnRego>N</reg:ConcessionOnRego><reg:Conditions><reg:RegistrationCondition><reg:CodeCategory>V</reg:CodeCategory><reg:Code>HE</reg:Code><reg:Description>HVIS EXEMPT - HVAIS INSP REQUIRED</reg:Description></reg:RegistrationCondition></reg:Conditions><reg:ConfigurationDetails><reg:Code>RT0</reg:Code><reg:Description>RIGID TRUCK (NO TRAILERS)</reg:Description></reg:ConfigurationDetails></ResponseDetails><SystemMessages><sys:Message><sys:Identifier>SUCCESS</sys:Identifier><sys:Classification>BUSINESS</sys:Classification><sys:Severity>SUCCESS</sys:Severity><sys:Message>Success</sys:Message></sys:Message></SystemMessages></NS3:getFreeRegoCheckByPlateNumberResponse></NS1:Body></NS1:Envelope>
--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146209@ibm.com>

%PDF-1.4
... rest ...
'''

spliter = data.split(b'\n', 1)[0]
print('spliter:', spliter)

all_items = data.split(spliter)[1:] # item [0] is empty
print('len:', len(all_items))
print('-----')

for item in all_items:
    headers, content = item.split(b'\n\n', 1)
    print(headers.decode().strip())
    print('-----')
    print(content[:100]) # display only part of long file
    print('-----')
```

Result:

```
spliter: b'--WMBMIME1Boundaryurn_uuid_6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146207'
len: 2
-----
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146208@ibm.com>
-----
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envel'
-----
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <1.urn:uuid:6C9A89293811DABC7F1563775146209@ibm.com>
-----
b'%PDF-1.4\n'
-----
```

Now you can save PDF and XML in file or parse XML.

Comment: thanks @furas! Much appreciate for taking your time to help a stranger :) All the best mate!